# How to connect to SQL server using pyodbc in a dag in airflow

Tags: python, docker, airflow, pyodbc, freetds

I have created an `airflow` environment using the docker image, in the docker image I have installed the `unixodbc-dev` library.

Now the airflow environment is working fine and the dags runs fine but when I use the python operator to connect via `pyodbc`. I am trying to connect using:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver{FreeTDS};Server=servername,1433;Database=dbname;Uid=username;Pwd=pass;")
```

It doesn't work and throws the error:

> ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'FreeTDS'
>   : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)").

Comment: What I have understood is I have not included the odbcinsti.ini file in the docker image while building the docker image, how to inlude it in the docker image? And what should be in that image I have found that I have this file which has this content, will it do? Content in file : [FreeTDS]Description=FreeTDS Driver Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so Setup=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so

Comment: Have you installed FreeTDS? Does that FreeTDS Driver file actually exist? If not, you may want to use the command [from this Gist if you're on Ubuntu](https://gist.github.com/kriwil/b49da8a5bc14504f73fe): `sudo apt-get install freetds-dev freetds-bin unixodbc-dev tdsodbc`. You can also try following [`pyodbc`'s guide for connecting to SQL Server from Linux](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Linux) to use Microsoft's drivers instead. I'm not too familiar with Docker so I'm not sure what else you might have to do to get it working.

Comment: See as I mentioned I haven't added the TDS driver, what I understood is I need t o add this file in the docker image, odbcinst.ini which will have this content: [FreeTDS]Description=FreeTDS Driver Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so Setup=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so  . Now I want to know that will this work? Is the path correct? Also if I install all this "sudo apt-get install freetds-dev freetds-bin unixodbc-dev tdsodbc" do I need to add any the odbcinst.in, again I want to connect via pyodbc to the sql server using the connection string I have mentioned. Thanks

Comment: When you add the `odbcinst.ini`, those paths you are including there need to point to actual files. You need to have the FreeTDS packages installed, as well as having that `odbcinst.ini` file present. I think the paths you have listed are correct, so see if you can get those installed and add the file to your image. Again, I'm not 100% sure about Docker, but I got this working on Ubuntu 18.04 with these steps.

Comment: Okay thanks I will update.

Comment: I tried everything but it is not working! :/ I can't understand that it should be an easy task to connect to a sql server but I'm still not able to by any means in a dag in airflow!

Comment: Did you also try using Microsoft's driver instead of FreeTDS? You might want to try the steps in [this Medium article](https://medium.com/analytics-and-data/setting-up-airflow-on-azure-connecting-to-ms-sql-server-8c06784a7e2b). Looks like there are some extra steps to get Airflow to connect to MSSQL from Docker images. Hope that can help.

Comment: I had read the article before and tried by installing few parts of the article, Now I have added all the required libraries as per the medium post, Now when I try to connect using their sql string in my dag, i.e connectionString = \
"mssql+pyodbc://{user}:{pwd}@{host}:{port}/{db}?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server". And after this i'm trying to do cursor=connectionstring.cursor() but it showing error that AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'cursor'.

Comment: You can't call `.cursor()` on the connection string. You have to actually get a `Connection` object by calling `pyodbc.connect(connection_string)`, then call the `.cursor()` on that object. You have it correct up there.

Comment: Yes you are right! I did that mistake but even after changing, it did not work! But after a lot of tries and installing a lot of libraries it is working now! I'm able to connect to SQL Server using pyodbc!  I will share the code in the answer! Thanks a lot for you help! :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have not installed and configured the FreeTDS driver.

I have had good luck using microsoft's ODBC driver.  Installation instructions for that are updated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).  Added benefit of using Microsoft's tooling is you get BCP.